# How can an element be grabbed with codeception?

Tags: php, automated-tests, codeception, acceptance-testing

Let's say we have the following HTML code:

```html
<div>
  <p id="fruit">Apple</p>
</div>
```

How do I grab `#fruit` and check its inner HTML via codeception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems, that Codeception utilizes either `executeJS` or `executeInSelenium`(not recommended) in
these kind of situations.

Here is an example using `executeJS` with JQuery:

```
<?php
  $fruitVal = $I->executeJS('return $(#fruit).val()');
?>
```

See more in: [Codeception docs: executeJS](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#executeJS)

---

Turns out, that there is another, "more natural" way to handle this case:

Here is an example using `grabAttributeFrom` method:

```
<?php
  $fruitVal = $I->grabAttributeFrom('#fruit', 'innerHTML');
?>
```

See more in: [Codeception docs: grabAttributeFrom](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#grabAttributeFrom)

Comment: btw not sure if innerHTML still works in latest codeCeption for HTML parsing. I tried a super simple test multiple times but everytime it's returning null.

Answer (score 1):

```php
$fruitVal = $I->grabAttributeFrom('#fruit', 'innerHTML');
```

No longer works.

Use this instead:

```php
$fruitVal = $I->grabTextFrom('#fruit');
```